# connecting 2 bezier curve segments

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have 2 closed segments made from bezier curves. ultimately these segments outline a surface i am trying to create. is there a way to join points between those 2 segments? then convert to mesh and create a surface

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that after creating your two paths, you convert each one to a mesh, then you Join <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> the two new meshes, then in Edit Mode you select segments of vertices on each side and make a new <kbd>F</kbd>ace.

The reason you should select a small segment at the time is if you were to take the whole thing there is a risk that it creates one large face that can cover the hole in the middle. You can use the <kbd>C</kbd>ircle select to grab a set of vertices.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: hey, that's what i've been doing but i was wondering if there was an automated way of creating such a surface by connecting bezier points so i can direct the concavity of the surface

Comment: Ah. Ok. Sorry I do not know of any automated way of doing it, or for your specific need.

Comment: "*i was wondering if there was an automated way of creating such a surface by connecting bezier points*" Blender already fills closed 2D curves with surfaces. Connecting midpoints points is neither possible nor the solution to your objective